# Show all messages fql

Tags: facebook-fql, message

i am currently using an fql query to retreive the body of a message and i'm doing it knowing only the thread id and the message count, for each message:

```
SELECT body FROM message WHERE message_id = '".$thread['thread_id']."_".$cnt."'
```

but i get this error:

> Uncaught Exception: 9: You are calling methods too frequently

and it takes minutes to execute. There is another way to retreive all the messages knowing only the thread_id?